# Chrome Driver Open New Profile With Selenium

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open chrommium wiht a differenr profile

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
        options.AddArgument(@"user-data-directory=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data");
        options.AddArgument(@"profile-directory=Default - Copy");
        driver1 = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Development\ChromeDrivers\96", options);
```

This is my user data directory which also has profile directly highlighted. (I just copied the Default folder)

[image]

My normal chrome browser has my profile logged in etc

[image]

but the chrome browser opened with code is different

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: any help please?

Comment: I did some searching myself, and all the other answers on StackOverflow basically say to write the code as you have written it. Are you sure you are not logged in to Chrome when Selenium opens it up? Have you tried navigating to any Google sites to see if it recognizes your user session? There might not actually be a problem.

Comment: The picture I have uploaded when chrome session starts, does not show me as logged in and no history and anything is maintained.